# Is the squircle a rational variety in $\mathbb Q$ or $\mathbb{F}_p$?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

It's well known that the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ is birational to a line by stereographic projection. Rational points on a circle can thus be described by a parametric equation with one parameter. I tried to derive a similar parametric equation for rational points on a squircle $x^4 + y^4 = 1$ but could not do it. So is this even possible? (i.e. is the squircle a rational variety in $\mathbb Q$) And is the situation different for finite fields?

Comment: There are no rational points on the squircle other than the four obvious ones.

Comment: Quick way of seeing Ethan's comment: if there were any other rational points $\langle\frac ab,\frac cd\rangle$ they would correspond to an integer solution to FLT for $n=4$, $(ad)^4+(bc)^4=(bd)^4$.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see the argument with FLT :) thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is impossible unless $p=2$. By the genus-degree formula, the arithmetic genus of the squircle is $\binom{4-1}{2}=3$, and as it's smooth except in characteristic two, that's the geometric genus too. But for curves, having a rational parametrization is equivalent to geometric genus zero.

In characteristic two, there is a map $t\mapsto (t,1-t)$, as $t^4+(1-t)^4=t^4+1-t^4=1$. But the squircle is not reduced in characteristic two, so this isn't an isomorphism anywhere like we commonly want for a parametrization.